# create folder and subfolder

Tags: bash, shell-script

[image]

Write a script that creates a folder hierarchy for your current academic semester. Your script should do the following:

1. Create a variable that holds the current semester name “Spring2021”.
2. Create an array that contains your courses for this semester.
3. Create an array that contains the folders you will create for each course which are: Slides, TMA, F-THE, essayQuiz.
4. Create a function that performs the following:
   a.  Accepts three variables: the first is string and the second and third are arrays. (5 marks)
   b.  Creates the following folders hierarchy:

```bsh
MY Code
#!/bin/bash

semester="spring2021"
courses=( "m109" "m105" )
folders=( "tma" "essayquiz" "fthe")

create() {
    echo mkdir $1
    echo cd $1
    
    for i in "${2}"
    do
        echo mkdir -p $i
        echo cd $i

        for j in "${3}"
        do
            echo mkdir $j
        done
        echo` cd ..`
        echocd ..
    done
}

create $semester ${courses[@]} ${folders[@]}
```

Comment: what isthe error         semester="spring2021"
courses=( "m109" "m105" )
folders=( "tma" "essayquiz" "f-the")

create()

{

echo `mkdir $1`

echo `cd $1`
for i in "${2}"

do

echo `mkdir -p $i`
echo `cd $i`
for j in "${3}"
do
echo `mkdir $j`
done
echo` cd ..`
echo`cd ..`
done
}
create $semester ${courses[@]} ${folders[@]}

Comment: Please [edit] your question, rather than adding additional information via comments

Comment: Also format your script properly and describe what happens when you run it.

Comment: If you need help with your coursework, then show what you have tried, where you are having trouble, and what isn't working rather than copying and pasting it here and asking for the work to be done for you.

Comment: @AndyDalton using echo like that is a very common and traditional method of getting a "dry-run" that only shows what a script would do, rather than actually doing it.  it works well (the only catch is you need to escape any metacharacters like redirection)

Comment: When passing multiple arrays to a shell function, you need to make sure they're passed by reference rather than by value, otherwise you just end up with a bunch of args to the function with no way of knowing which arg belongs to which array.   In short, use `local -n` to define the arrays within the function.   See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10953834 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know how to pass arrays into a function. The method you are currently using is not doing what you think it is. `$4` would equal `tma` instead try declaring by using `local -n` and settings a variable with a DIFFERENT name than the variables that will be passed to the function. I believe this will apply as long as you are using a version of bash4.3 or newer. By utilizing `local -n` you will be able to set variables in the fashion you are expecting.

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                                   
                                                                                                               
semester="spring2021"                                                                                          
courses=( "m109" "m105" )                                                                                      
folders=( "tma" "essayquiz" "fthe")                                                                            
                                                                                                               
create() {                                                                                                     
                                                                                                               
local -n _semester=$1                                                                                          
local -n _courses=$2                                                                                           
local -n _folders=$3                                                                                           
                                                                                                               
for i in "${_courses[@]}"                                                                                        
do                                                                                                             
     for j in "${_folders[@]}"                                                                                   
     do                                                                                                        
          mkdir -p "$_semester/$i/$j"                                                                     
     done                                                                                                      
done                                                                                                           
                                                                                                               
                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                              
create semester courses folders
```

Keep in mind there are other ways of accomplishing what you are trying to do here. Although I am not an expert in bash so I simply followed your script style, refined it and this is the end result. I believe that this may be accomplished without for loops although I have no idea how that would be done.

Also it is always good practice to check your script before posting it here. I personally use [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) which works very well.

Comment: Also, you should double quote the array variables when you use them, in case any of the elements contain spaces or other annoying characters.  e.g. `for i in "${_courses[@]}"`.    As a general rule, unless you have a specific, known reason why you don't want to quote a variable in a specific instance, you should always double-quote variables when you use them.  (and there are very few reasons/instances why/when not quoting is useful or desirable).

Comment: @cas Fair enough. Actually knew this but figured since I knew all the names it would be fine but you have a good point.